How to connect to existing logged in chrome instance in Playwright on MacOs?
My goal is to automate a task on a website that requires login. So I want to login once manually and let the automation run from there. I tried using CRD but when my code runs, it opens a new window where my account is not logged in. Here is an example code I am running:
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import time


def connect_to_chrome_debugger():
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        # Connect to the running Chrome instance using CDP
        browser = p.chromium.connect_over_cdp("http://localhost:9234")

        # Create a new page in the connected browser
        page = browser.new_page()

        # Navigate to a URL
        page.goto("https://gmail.com")
        time.sleep(10)

        # Print the title of the page
        print(page.title())

        # Perform additional actions as needed

        # Close the page (not the entire browser)
        page.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect_to_chrome_debugger()

Now in this example, I have already logged into my gmail on chrome and when I launch the CRD session using:
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --remote-debugging-port=9234

it shows me as logged in user. However, when playwright runs and opens a new window, then it behaves as if I am logged out.
